Can you nest Spring Boot Application Executions? (nested calls to run(...)?)
Hello Stackoverflow :),
to give some context, I mostly single-handedly develop an application, which runs tests with Cucumber and TestNG. The whole applications runs with spring boot and I took extra care to allow parallelism everywhere. I now want to extend the application with a very simple and easy to maintain frontend which allows the execution of test runs via a GUI.
The Spring Application with the GUI is a separate @SpringBootConfiguration, which would spawn yet another separate @SpringBootConfiguration for executions which are started via the GUI. So I have 3 Configurations:

Configuration for CI/CD purposes
Configuration for GUI purposes with an extra controller
Configuration to be started from the GUI Configuration

The execution of the 3. Configuration happens inside a POST controller method and looks something like this:
CompleteableFuture.runAsync(() -> new SpringApplicationBuilder().OMITTED.run(..., ..., ...));

The 3. Configuration currently does not work when executed from inside the JAR, only when executed via IntelliJ. When @EnableAutoConfiguration is activated, it says something about not finding the spring.factories file. Without, it simply can not find the appropriate sources.
Is this approach possible / viable? Or is there maybe a better approach for my use case? Note that I want to reduce complexity where possible and really just need a simple frontend. I'd also prefer it, if my @ConfigurationProperties stay immutable.
Versions:

Spring-Boot: 2.6.3
Java: 11

EDIT:
I'll assume this kind of control flow / execution is not meant by Spring. I'll switch to RequestScoped beans to get the proper lifetimes and work with that.

The issue you're facing likely relates to how Spring Boot handles classpath and resource loading when running from a JAR file v/s running from an IDE like IntelliJ/ vscode
a approach to manually specify configuration :-
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .sources(MyConfigurationClass.class)
    .properties("spring.config.name=myapp")
    .run(args));

If the issue persists, you might want to look into the exact error message related to spring.factories and the way resorces are bundled in your JAR (you can inspect the JAR structure using tools like jar tf .jar).
If it does'nt work Try Adding logging or debug statements to verify that the spring.factories file and other resources are being loaded correctly :)

The issues Spring is giving me don't make sense. The other 2 Configurations also use auto configuration and share a very similar set of spring sources and they work.
There also is not spring.factories file bundled into my JAR.
The next best thing would probably to debug the spring sources but that is something I don't yet want to do.

Since you mentioned no spring.factories file is bundled in your jAR, ensure that your dependencies include the necessary Spring Boot starters and other libraries. You can add a custom spring.factories file if needed....

Even when I disable auto configuration for the 3. Configuration, the Spring container will fail searching for the appropriate sources. That is, the first @Autowired occurence will lead tho error, that an instance for the class can not be found / created. Of course only inside the JAR.
